# How do I write js code to print serial number, odd numbers and even numbers from 1 to 100 in a tabular form?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S/N</th>
<th>Odd</th>
<th>Even</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
var insertNewRow = function(even, odd){
  var tableRef =  document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
  var serialNum = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var evenCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var oddCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var serialNumber = document.createTextNode(i);
  var evenNumber = document.createTextNode(i);
  var OddNumber = document.createTextNode(j);
  serialNum.appendChild(serialNumber); 
  evenCell.appendChild(evenNumber);
  oddCell.appendChild(OddNumber);
}
for(i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++){
  if(i % 2 == 0){    
    var j = i -1;
    insertNewRow( i, i, j)
  } 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

| **OUTPUT** |
| --- |
| **S/N** | **Even** |
| :-------- | -------: |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 10 |
| 6 | 12 |
| 7 | 14 |
| 8 | 16 |
| 9 | 18 |
| 10 | 20 |

The above is just an example of how the output should look like using 1 - 20 as a case study. The output should be in this order above but from 1 to 100.

Comment: Welcome! It looks like you already have some code. Please edit your question to be specific: what is your issue? What is your input, expected output, actual output, errors, etc? Currently you just included a big code block with no further info

Comment: What is the expected output? What is the serial number supposed to be?

Comment: The serial number is supposed to be from 1, 2, 3, 4,.... 100, sequentially. This is example of how the overall output should be look like:
OUTPUT

Comment: But your table will only have 50 rows, so how can the serial number run from 1 to 100?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the table as it should appear in the output

Comment: What will be the *last* row of the output table? Will it be `50 | 99 | 100` or `100 | 199 | 200`?

Comment: The serial number should end at 100 while the rest ends at 200. Also, the column for the odd numbers should have red background color and the even numbers column should have green background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that:

- The function `insertNewRow` expects two arguments, but you call it with three
- The serial number is given the same value (`i`) as the even row number (also `i`), while the serial number should be a different number, ... the number of the row in the output table.
- There is an empty row in the initial HTML that is never populated. Just remove that from the initial HTML
- Apparently you want to output 100 rows in your table, but your code only creates 50 new rows.

Some other remarks:

- There is no need to pass an argument to the `insertRow` method: the default is that the row is appended at the end
- Similarly, you can call the `insertCell` method in left-to-right order and omit the argument
- Instead of creating text nodes, you can just assign the text to the `textContent` property of the `td` node. That way you don't even need a variable assignment for such node.
- With `querySelector` you can select the `tbody` element with one method call.
- There is no need to select this `tbody` element for each row -- it will always be the same element, so only select it once.
- Instead of skipping iterations that correspond to an odd number, simplify the main loop logic, and insert a row in each iteration, but using the iteration value for the serial number, the double of that for the *even* column, and one less for the *odd* column.

This leads to the following code:

```js
let tableRef =  document.querySelector('#myTable > tbody');

for (let rowNumber = 1 ; rowNumber <= 100; rowNumber++) {
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow();
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = rowNumber;         // serial
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = rowNumber * 2 - 1; // odd
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = rowNumber * 2;     // even
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td, th { border: 1px solid; text-align: right}
td:nth-child(2) { background: pink }
td:last-child { background: lightblue }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>Odd</th>
      <th>Even</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But what if I want to add red background color to the odd column and green background color to the even column?

Comment: how do I go about that?

Comment: You can use CSS for that. Just search for "CSS column background"... If you cannot make it work, ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Although rather long-winded, your code will work with a few changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S/N</th>
<th>Odd</th>
<th>Even</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
var insertNewRow = function(i,odd,even){
  var tableRef =  document.getElementById('myTable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);
  var oddCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var evenCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var serialNum = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var serialNumber = document.createTextNode(i);
  var evenNumber = document.createTextNode(even);
  var OddNumber = document.createTextNode(odd);
  serialNum.appendChild(serialNumber);
  oddCell.appendChild(OddNumber);
  evenCell.appendChild(evenNumber);
}
for(let i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++){
  if(i % 2 == 0){    
var j = i -1;
insertNewRow( i, i, j)
  } 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main changes:**

- I made sure your function accepts three instead of only two arguments: `insertNewRow = function(i,odd,even){...}`
- inside the function I only use the passed parameters and not some uncertain global variables (like `i` and `j` before)
- I reversed the order of your `newRow.insertCell(0)` statements.

A shorter version of the script could look like this:

```js
for (var arr=[],i=1;i<100;i+=2)
arr.push(`<tr><td>${i}:</td><td>${i}</td><td>${i+1}</td></tr>`);
document.querySelector("tbody").innerHTML=arr.join("\n");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S/N</th>
<th>Odd</th>
<th>Even</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```